# How to sort nth column columns in text file

Tags: python, sorting

So my data looks like this:

```
1 3456542  5 may 2014
2 1245678  4 may 2014
3 4256876  2 may 2014
4 5643156  6 may 2014
.....
```

I want to sort the 2nd column of 7 digit ID numbers from greatest to least.  Also depending on the first number in the ID number I'd like to send each row to a different text file (i.e. for all the ID numbers that start with 3, send that entire row into a text file, for all the ID numbers that start with 1 send that entire row to another text file... and so on).  What is the easiest way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Stackoverflow is not a free code service. Voting to close as off-topic

Comment: There is no easy way, if you haven't attempted anything. But yes, Pandas  package is what you need.

http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: I wasn't asking for an answer, I was asking where to start conceptually.

Comment: The data can probably be read using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. The list [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method takes optional arguments that will allow you to control what part of each row is used to do the sorting. This will require all the data to be read into memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using pandas.  That makes it really easy.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

txt = StringIO('''
a b        c d   e
1 3456542  5 may 2014
2 1245678  4 may 2014
3 4256876  2 may 2014 
4 5643156  6 may 2014
''')
df = pd.read_csv(txt, delim_whitespace=True)
df.sort('b', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input data is text, I would start by separating lines from each other and columns within lines. See the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function for this.

The result should be a list of lists. You can then sort by the second column with the `sort()` or `sorted()` function if you provide the keyword argument `key=`. You might have to convert the number columns to int so that they will be sorted from small to large (and not alphabetical).

For the last part of your question, you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which provides you with a grouping functionality like you requested.

This should get you started. Another option would be to use pandas.

Answer (score 0):

"I wasn't asking for an answer, I was asking where to start conceptually."

Start reading the text file using [`file.readlines`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm), split the data using [`line.strip().split(" ", 2)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) wich will give you data in the following format:

`['1', '3456542', ' 5 may 2014']`

Now you should be able to complete your task.

Hint: look up the builtin functions [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

Answer (score 0):

Heres my way of doing it:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

#read in file
file_lines = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        file_lines.append(row)

#sort
file_lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

#write sorted file
with open("test_sorted.txt", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in file_lines:
        writer.writerow(row)

#separate files
for row in file_lines:
    file_num = row[1][0]
    with open("file_{0}.txt".format(file_num), "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: How would you write more than 1 row to each txt output file?